# Background image flickering in a div

Tags: image, html, flicker

I am using asp.net

I have cached images on the client using javascript and I load an image every 300 milliseconds. On Chrome no problems.  On IE9+10 I get a flicker. I thought if cached the images 1st I would avoid the flicker?

I have also tried using 2 divs. 1 that is hidden and loads the next frame and the 2nd div to display the background image from the 1st div (once it has loaded) but I still get a flicker.

Really confused...

my code:

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="Play Motion Clip from Beginning">
<img alt="Play Motion" src="../Images/play_green_controls.png" style="border-style: none; width: 32px; height: 32px; background-color: #000000; cursor: pointer;"
            id="btnPlay" />
</a>
<div id="divImage" >
hello andy
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cache = [];
    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
    var interval = 100;
    var _total = 0;

    $("#btnPlay").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default3.aspx/GetClips",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                cache = [];
                 _total = 0;
                $.each(msg.d, function () {
                    var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
                    cacheImage.src = this['Text'];
                    cache[_total] = cacheImage;
                    _total++;
                }
                );
                setInterval('swapImages()', interval);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
    var div = document.getElementById('divImage');
    var _index = 0;
    function swapImages() {

        if (_index < _total) {              
            if (_index > 0) {
                div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            }               
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
        else {
            interval = 0;
        }
        _index++;
        if (_index  == _total)
        {
            div.removeChild(cache[_index - 1]);
            _index = 0;
            div.appendChild(cache[_index]);
        }
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList GetClips()
    {
        ArrayList _arr = new ArrayList();
        int _max = 250;  //seems to be safe
        string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Cloud\Catalogues\000EC902F17F\2\2013\10\6\10\f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8","*.jpg"); //731
           for (int _index = 0; _index < _files.Length; _index++)
        {
            string _file = _files[_index];
            string[] _bits = _file.Split('\\');
            string _url = "Portal/Catalogues/000EC902F17F/2/2013/10/6/10/f1fe61da-4684-48ed-a503-4a5586ece9c8/" + _bits[10];
            ListItem _item = new ListItem();
            _item.Text = _url;
            _arr.Add(_item);
            if (_index == _max - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return _arr;
    }
```

Comment: can i see the code you use for this

Comment: @Vickey sure. 2 secs..

Comment: @Vickey  this was what I was using originally. I later tried using div backgrounds. The flickering occurred on both img and div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was interested. I did this:

I added a hidden img control. I loaded the image to that and on the onload event I called a function to load the img.src into the div background.Which so far appears to work.